# What is the difference in the usage of the methods firstObject vs objectAtIndex:0?

Tags: ios, nsarray

Today I have tested using firstObject and objectAtIndex:0. If the array has the size of 0, using the former does not cause a crash while the latter causes a crash. So I'm thinking that it's better to use firstObject than objectAtIndex:0. But are there pitfalls in using firstObject over objectAtIndex:0?

I have also been reading through the [NSArray documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and I am surprised and wondering why they did not mention this fact on the documentation.

Comment: If all you ever need is the zeroth object, `firstObject` is fine.  It would be silly to check a variable index and use `firstObject` if it's zero, `objectAtIndex` otherwise.

Comment: In our code, we have many instances that we use objectAtIndex:0 to access an object. usually we just need any object that's all

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is one ***key*** difference. Using `firstObject` returns `nil` if there is none. Using `objectAtIndex:0` will crash your app(throws an exception) if there is no object there.From a user experience perspective, crashing is highly advocated against, so it is safer to use `firstObject`.

***BUT*** the biggest pitfall: `firstObject` has been available since iOS 4, but was a private API until iOS 7.

Comment: An array not being the size you expected is the result of a logic error. A crash is often safer than attempting to carry on.

Comment: @ChrisDevereux good point there. I will analyze our code to see which message is applicable to use depending on the situation

Comment: Yes, but al least you can check for nil rather crash the app, which ultimately looks bad for an average user...

Comment: @vborra On the user perspective, I think it's better if the app does not crash. Maybe I will just add a logic to check if the result is nil so as to avoid bugs.